# Optional.ofNullable com ifPresent

Tags: java, java-8

Se a propriedade `ano` estiver null mas o modelo e o ano estiverem preenchidas, irá salvar os dados do carro no repositório ?

```
public Class Carro {
 int ano;
 String modelo;
 int valor;
}

public void carro(final Carro carro){
 Carrorepository carroRepository;
Optiona.ofNullable(carro).ifPresent({
carroRepository.save(carro)
 });
}
```

Comment: A propriedade `ano` não pode estar nula porque é um `int`, não um `Integer`. De toda sorte, o `ifPresent` vai julgar quem está no `Optional` e em seus subsequentes mapeamentos, então ele irá chamar sim a função de salvar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas na questão. O primeiro é de linguagem mesmo: "se `ano` estiver null mas [...] ano estiver preenchido".

[image: Algo de errado não está certo]

Ok, vamos assumir que foi um engano e se desejava se referir ao terceiro campo do `Carro`, o campo `valor`, como estando preenchido.

O outro problema é de tipagem. Qualquer combinações de bits torna um número binário válido. Então se existisse um valor que representasse o nulo para o `int` dever-se-ia escolher algum número inteiro válido que iria representar esse nulo, diminuindo então o alcance dos números inteiros. E várias outras complicações.

Os nulos só existem para *objetos* no mundo Java. Há algum nulo para inteiro? Sim, existe, mas não é com o `int`. É com a classe invólucro `Integer`. As variáveis dessa classe ou são invólucros de `int` ou estão apontando para `null`. Dito isto, vou assumir que isso foi um engano de digitação que, quando fosse testar o código, a equipe de desenvolvimento ficaria coçando o cabelo quando aparecesse um 0 onde se esperava um `null`...

O último problema é o lambda. Existem duas notações para lambda no Java: notações flecha `->` para função declarada no lambda, e a notação duplo-dois-pontos `::` para referência de método de instância, método estático e construtores. No caso, parece que você desejava ter usado a notação flecha:

```
c -> { carroRepository.save(c); }
```

Porém, como se espera um `Consumer<Carro>` e não se faz outra operação, poderíamos usar a notação lambda de um único comando, que não precisa dos indicadores de bloco de código:

```
c -> carroRepository(c)
```

Porém mais uma vez, só se faz o uso de um método. Direto isso. Poder-se-ia fazer a chamada a referência a esse método:

```
carroRepository::save
```

Pronto, vamos ao que importa.

O `Optional` olha simplesmente para o objeto que ele está envolvendo. Não olha para o conteúdo desse objeto (portanto, a priori, ignora tais campos completamente).

O `Optional.ofNullable` pode assumir dois valores:

- `Optional.empty`, uma variável estática que representa um objeto que está ausente
- um envelope contendo o objeto em questão

Caso seja o primeiro caso, o `ifPresent` **nunca** será executado. Fim de papo. Já, se for o segundo caso, o método que consome objetos da classe envolvida será chamado **sempre**.

Existem casos em que se pega um `Optional` preenchido e se obtém um `Optional` vazio. Os principais que me lembro são:

- `map`, que transforma o objeto envolvido em outro (muitas vezes um campo desse objeto, mas não necessariamente)
- `filter`, que transforma explicitamente em um `Optional.empty` caso o predicado não seja atendido

Então, dito isso, como não se chama nenhum `filter` nem `map` sobre o `Optional` criado sobre a variável `carro`, caso `carro != null`, então o método `carroRepository::save` será chamado e o carro será salvo.

---

Leitura recomendada:

- [26 razões que usar `Optional` corretamente não é opcional](https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional)